# Displaying Master Detail Response in Postman

Tags: java, json, rest, postman, oracle-adf

I have an Oracle ADF Application which has a master-detail structure. My application works fine, but when I am inserting a master-detail record, my detail object is not being displayed in the response but in a link.

So, how can I make the application display the detail info along with master. My request and response are like following. Thanks a lot.

---------------------Request-------------------------------------------------

```
{

      "ChqCode": "value",
      "ChqAmt": 1234,
      "ChqBankCompCode": "value",
      "ChqCompCode": "value",
      "PayViewObj":[
        {
          "PaCompCode": "value",
          "PaChqCompCode": "value"
        }
   ]
}
```

-------------------------Response--------------------------

```
{
  "ChqCode": "value",
  "ChqAmt": 1234,
  "ChqBankCompCode": "value",
  "ChqCompCode": "value",
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:7101/ap-rest-api/rest/1/manualcheck/5100",
      "name": "manualcheck",
      "kind": "item"
    },
    {
      "rel": "canonical",
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:7101/ap-rest-api/rest/1/manualcheck/5100",
      "name": "manualcheck",
      "kind": "item"
    },
    {
      "rel": "child",
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:7101/ap-rest-api/rest/1/manualcheck/5100/child/PayViewObj",
      "name": "PayViewObj",
      "kind": "collection"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. It's a limitation from ADF framework. Upon POST, once a record is inserted it performs a GET (alike operation) on the inserted record and delivers the same as response payload for your POST.

For your POST operation, the response payload is a confirmation of the data inserted.

To ensure your insert is successful you should rely on the response status 201. But validation of data POSTed is best done using a successive GET operation. In which case you can additionally get the child resources from the links.